# Fetching into non-bare repository with bitbake

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

Looks like I am facing a trivial issue, but I am not able to figure out anything.
I was trying to bitbake the raspberry pi image and due to bad internet connection, it failed. Now when I retried to bitbake again, it gives me the below error.

> fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of
>   non-bare repository

I understand that, this is because my git repository is no longer bare. After searching a lot on the internet, I found only one solution. Running the below command will probably fix the issue.

> bitbake -c cleanall

As per my understanding this will clear most of the contents of the build directory of poky. I want to avoid this. Is there any way I can continue bitbaking without cleaning all the stuff that I have downloaded so far ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what package is failing (and bitbake tells that), after that doing something like

```
$ bitbake -c cleansstate $PACKAGE_NAME
$ rm -fr ${DL_DIR}/git2/$REPOSITORY
```

(where `$PACKAGE_NAME` is your package name, `${DL_DIR}` is the variable from `local.conf` (defaults to `build/downloads`) and `$REPOSITORY` is the repository (URL from the recipe) for this `$PACKAGE_NAME`) should be enough.

Comment: This probably work. But after rebooting my PC, poky recovered itself.

Comment: Please consider the above comment as the **real** answer to this question. Just faced the same problem and, at the very end, after hours of workarounds, I solved just rebooting my PC.

Comment: For me worked to remove the ./git2/github.com.project_name.git and .done file.
I am using SRCREV with git hash to speed up the process of fetching.
So probably after fetching some version of project, and then update this SRCREV hash the git repo would have already one commit which is causing some problems for bitbake git fetcher.